# How to iterate through some div's and then check if value is less or equal to date?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a christmas calendar, with a lot of links, and then the links should become active, if the hatch number is less or equal to the date.

So I have a lot of div's, which I have placed randomly, and I want jQuery to go through these div's, get their value, and then check if the value is less or equal to the date. Which means they should be active.

This is what I've got so far!

```
var value = $('.hatch').text()

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();

if (value <= n) { 
return;

} else {
$("a").removeAttr('href');
return;
}
```

But this only works one specific hatch/div.

Any idea how to do this iteration on 24 hatches/div?

Any help much obliged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea, what exactly you want to do depending on the value being lower or greater, but this should iterate over all elements (not only divs) with the class hatch:

```
$('.hatch').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
   // now check against your date and do whatevery you want.
   // this is the current div being checked
});
```

Comment: If I do as you propose, it only takes the first div, changes it, or not, and does the same to the rest. Say I have six div's with the same class, and each has a different text value/number. I want it the function to change every div where it's text/value is larger than the day date (day number).